# Writing a javascript function which accepts a single array argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Please write a function called lastElement which accepts a single array argument. The function should return the last element of the array (without removing the element). If the array is empty, the function should return null.

1. lastElement([3,5,7]) //7
2. lastElement([1]) //1
3. lastElement([]) //null

```
** the code that I wrote **

let array = [3, 5, 7];

function lastElement (array) { 
    return array[array.length - 1];
}
```

I'm flummoxed on the last part with the function returning null if the array if empty.

Comment: You are writing a new question on Stackoverflow just to ask "How do I know if an array is empty"? :|

Comment: Don't let downvotes grind you down. Either you didn't know (in which case you're in the right place) or you had a mental block, in which case you're in the right place. :-)

Comment: If you want the easiest for beginners :

function lastElement(array){
    if(array.length === 0){
        return null
    } else 
    {
        return array[array.length - 1]
    }
    
}

Answer (score 3):

You can update your code a tiny bit to check if the array is empty and then return null like this:

```js
return array.length ? array[array.length - 1] : null;
```